# Making system, that makes possible writing code through debug

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, compilation

For my university course I want to make system for learning programming. The main idea is writing code through debug, just look at picture (from Bret Victor video):

[image]

I don't want to make my own compiler (just becouse it's very complicated and hard, especially for C# language), so I want use all features of .NET and other libraries. I see there two ways:

- Rewrite code by replacing assigments to assigment & sending debug information to main program
- Compile code and debug it -> ...

Anyway, I need some start point. What classes and libraries I must google, in which manuals I can read useful information, what is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what could work is, if you just treat C# as a script language. There are multiple tutorials on how to use C# within C# as a script language, like [this](http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/02/treating-c-like-a-scripting-language/) one. So you just start the "script" compiler again on predefined conditions (like a line break) and if the compilation is successfull you return the result in your second pane. This is just a basic idea.

Comment: The problem - I need full state of all variables in code, not just result. As I know, CSharpCodeProvider just compiles source file (and then we can invoke compiled method). I can't access names of local variables from reflection.